# React native can't run in ios by command but it can run in Xcode?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I used two libraries: "native-base" and "react-native-elements" but when I used it, I could not use the command `react-native run-ios`. But when I open the Xcode project, it can run and work as well.

This is my error below when I try to use the command `react-native run-ios`:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening DesignComponents.xcodeproj

One more error:

> The following build commands failed:
>           Analyze /Users/my_path_project/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTAssert.m normal x86_64
>   (1 failure)

I try to resolve it by clean cache, clean folder node_modules and something that I can, but it's not working.